# How can I convert an integer to date without clock?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataset. In first column values an integer type YYYYMMDD. I want to convert it to date without clock (hour,second) and replace with column's values.

How can I convert an integer to date in Python? I use JupyterLab.

Comment: When you say you have an integer with YYYYMMDD, do you literally mean that there are four digits for the year, then two for month, then two for day, in the same integer? Like the number 20190820 equates to August 20, 2019?

Comment: I meant 20191203. 2019 is year. 12 is month and 03 is day. and ı want to change it. ı want create 3 table more and years at table, month at a table and day at a table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you have a dataset, let the name of the dataset be `df` then using pandas, you could do:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Dates.astype(str),format = "%Y%m%d")
```